# Google Places API nearby search missing places

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am attempting to find the nearest building/place name using the Google Places API but have been confused by why some places are not included in the results even if you entered the exact coordinates.

For example, if I searched Google Maps for "UCLA Murphy Hall", google maps is able to find the building and return its Geocode. However, if you entered that Geocode into the Nearby search API, the returned results does not include the building regardless of search radius.

My questions are:

- Why is there a difference in what you can search via google maps text search vs what you can get from nearby API?
- If I want to be able to find the name of the building from the geocode (34.0715597,-118.4392192), what should I be using?
- What is the best approach to map a geocode -> Nearest full street address (with street number) -> nearest building/business?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code from an old project of mine reagarding:

- What is the best approach to map a geocode -> Nearest full street
  address (with street number)

first function gets the nearest street coords based on the lat & lng you provide
second function gets the formatted address of the coords that first function returned

```
    // get nearest coords based on given tracking
tb.prototype.getNearestStreetCoords = function(lat, lng, callback) {

    var parentClass = this;

    var nearestStreet = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng
    };

    if (parentClass.useNearest != true) callback(nearest); 

    var request = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {


        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {       
            callback(response);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }

    });     
}

    // get nearest formatted address based on lat & lng
tb.prototype.getAddress = function(lat, lng, callback) {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback(results[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }

    }); 
}
```

**UPDATE**

Distance calculation function, between 2 lat - lng points written in php.

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit = 'M') {

        $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);

        if ($unit == 'K') {
            return ($miles * 1.609344);
        } else if ($unit == 'N') {
            return ($miles * 0.8684);
        } else {
            return $miles;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see, I was reading about similar approaches. Are you able to comment on any of the other questions I had?

Comment: I haven;t looked into places api. Is there a way to get the places near your location? Perhaps then you might be able to get the place closer to you? I'll update my answer with 1 more function which determines the distance between 2 lat&lng points in case you need it.It's written in php but the conversion is easy.

Comment: I think I am asking a bit too much of Google Places API haha. Thanks for your answer though. I will accept

Answer (score 1):

For turning geocodes into full street addresses, I'd suggest you try our Reverse Geocoding service. Using the above location coordinates, reverse geocoding returns "410 Charles E Young Drive, UCLA, Los Angeles, CA 90024, USA"

- Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding
- Example request: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.0715597,-118.4392192&sensor=true_or_false

Comment: Right, this has two problems however. First is that I don't get the name of the building back, and the second is that if I only have a coordinate that is very close (within 2m) of the coordinate given then reverse geocoding alot of times does not return a street address with the address number (it only returns a street name).